# Notepad++ wildcard

Tags: notepad++

how to find and replace all characters after the main domain (including the "/" character) using a wild card?

For example, i have the following 4 rows:

```
intersport-schaeftlmaier.de/
weymouthhondapowersports.com/Default.asp
rtbstream.com/click?data=RG1kUFJQQUYw
top-casino-sites.com/
```

**In excel I would simply use the following:**
Find this /*
Replace with this

**The results will look like this:**

```
intersport-schaeftlmaier.de
weymouthhondapowersports.com
rtbstream.com
top-casino-sites.com
```

So, how to do that with notepad++ ?

Thanks,
Ziv

Answer (score 22):

In the Find and Replace dialog:

- under Search Mode select Regular Expression
- set Find What to `/.*$`
- leave Replace With empty

This is replace any slash and all the text after it until the end of line with nothing.  It uses a regular expression so it looks convoluted but it is well worth learning as regular expressions are insanely useful for lots of things.

Basically:

- `/` isn't a special character so it just matches a `/`
- `.` is a wildcard that matches a single character.  To match a literal `.` use `\.`
- `*` is a wildcard that matches zero of more of the preceding character.  So `a*` would match zero or more `a` and `.*` would match zero of more of any character.
- `$` matches the end of a line.  To match a literal `$` use `\$`

A few other special characters:

- `\` is the escape character - use it to turn special characters into normal characters.  Yo match a literal `\` use `\\`
- `+` is a wildcard that matches one of more of the preceding character.  So `a+` would match one or more `a` and `.+` would match one of more of any character.
- `^` matches the start of a line.  To match a literal `^` use `\^`
- `(` and `)` make a match group.  To match literal `(` or `)` use `\(` and `\)`

And there are more special characters including `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` along with others that I won't mention.

Answer (score 2):

Use Regular Expression in Replace and then use this:

```
/.*
```

Untick the . matches newline and ofc replace it with nothing ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may use (better regexp as Excel)

```
/.*
```

So:

[image: Notepad search replace]

Comment: In my case I didn't need `/` I only typed `.*` for example I was searching for `script.*scr` in a document to find `<script async src="stackoverflow,com"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

`Search` -> `Replace`. In the `Find what` box, enter the following Regex:

```
/.*$
```

In the `Replace with` box, enter nothing. Make sure `Search Mode` is set to `Regular expression`. Then `Find Next`/`Replace` or `Replace All` as you see fit.

How it works:

`/` matches `/`, ensuring we start from the `/` after the domain name.
`.*` matches any character any number of times.
`$` anchors the match to the end of the line.

In summary, this regex looks for `/` followed by any number of characters, all the way to the end of the line.