# Notepad++ wildcard replace: String match to end of line (replace with empty)

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Everything found at the word `|Agristats` and beyond to the end of the line should be deleted.

I have tried a couple things which do not appear to working-- `|Agristats.*$` and `|Agristats*$`.  References I have consulted are-- [SuperUser: remove-the-last-part-of-every-line-in-notepad](https://superuser.com/questions/391318/how-do-i-remove-the-last-part-of-every-line-in-notepad) and [Notepad++ wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742519/notepad-wildcard).

Need help solving this, please!

**INPUT**

```
0011  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS WINGS            | 0000029| 0001423.11|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-17$'
0012  |86|19|EVIS SALVAGE - BONELESS BREAST|-0000019|-0001080.38|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-17$'
0013  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS DARK MEAT        | 0000024| 0000859.95|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-17$'
0011  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS WINGS            |-0000022|-0001687.17|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-24$'
0012  |86|19|EVIS SALVAGE - BONELESS BREAST| 0000000| 0000063.71|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-24$'
0013  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS DARK MEAT        | 0000016| 0000956.60|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-24$'
0018  |88|19|SMALL FRONT HALF SALVAGE      | 0000045| 0003087.42|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'2-24$'
0227  |78|19|DISJOINTED WING W/O TIP (6377,|-0000019|-0035659.00|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'12-2$'
0438  |78|19|WIP BLSL FILET 3.5OZ - 8.75OZ |-0000019|-0035218.00|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'12-2$'
0611  |78|19|SLIT BL SL BREAST FILET      (|-0000019|-0036078.05|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'12-2$'
1525  |78|19|WOG 2.50-DN  14HD CW  BF      |-0000790|-0024238.08|Agristats new trial_200 (edited).xlsx|'12-2$'
```

**OUTPUT (desired)**

```
0011  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS WINGS            | 0000029| 0001423.11
0012  |86|19|EVIS SALVAGE - BONELESS BREAST|-0000019|-0001080.38
0013  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS DARK MEAT        | 0000024| 0000859.95
0011  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS WINGS            |-0000022|-0001687.17
0012  |86|19|EVIS SALVAGE - BONELESS BREAST| 0000000| 0000063.71
0013  |86|19|SALVAGE EVIS DARK MEAT        | 0000016| 0000956.60
0018  |88|19|SMALL FRONT HALF SALVAGE      | 0000045| 0003087.42
0227  |78|19|DISJOINTED WING W/O TIP (6377,|-0000019|-0035659.00
0438  |78|19|WIP BLSL FILET 3.5OZ - 8.75OZ |-0000019|-0035218.00
0611  |78|19|SLIT BL SL BREAST FILET      (|-0000019|-0036078.05
1525  |78|19|WOG 2.50-DN  14HD CW  BF      |-0000790|-0024238.08
```

**Replace Dialogue**

I do not understand why the replace prompt says `Replaced All: 1,223 occurrences were replaced`, and yet the file looks exactly the same with not changes made.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the '|' in regex

Change it to `\|Agristats.*$` and do a replace all.

The reason why you are getting a result 1223 occurences were replaced is also simply due to the fact that the regex you wrote is matching a postion. These are called zero length match.

Comment: You need 'multiline' set.

Comment: @PoulBak since it's notepad++ won't replace all will do the same thing ?

Comment: Ok, you're propably right, I'm don't know much about Notepad++.

Comment: @karthick So `|` is a special character-- I did not realize that?  Is there a list somewhere of all regex special characters?

Comment: @SherlockSpreadsheets don't remember anything top of the head. But a quick search showed this link which has lot of info https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: @karthick- Thanks for solving the problem, and for the providing the link.  So the pipe character is a part of the "Logic" group... good to know!